# Trying to understand complex enum in Swift 5

Tags: swift, types, enums

I am using a package that has the following in it:

```
public enum DateValue {
    case dateOnly(Date)
    case dateAndTime(Date)
}


extension DateValue: Codable {
    static let errorMessage = "Date string does not match format expected by formatter."
    
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let value = try container.decode(String.self)
        if let date = DateFormatter.iso8601Full.date(from: value) {
            self = .dateAndTime(date)
            return
        }

        if let date = DateFormatter.iso8601DateOnly.date(from: value) {
            self = .dateOnly(date)
            return
        }

        throw Swift.DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(
            in: container,
            debugDescription: Self.errorMessage
        )
    }
    
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        let value: String
        switch self {
        case .dateOnly(let date):
            value = DateFormatter.iso8601DateOnly.string(from: date)
        case .dateAndTime(let date):
            value = DateFormatter.iso8601Full.string(from: date)
        }

        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(value)
    }
}
```

In Xcode 13.2.1 I see this in the debugger:

[image: Debugger]

So, I have theStartDate as a DataValue type but want to access it as a Foundation.Date. I would think this is simple, as I am sure it is, but this is over my head in Swift skills.

I am truly at a loss for how to do this and I think my main issue is not understanding how the emun and extension work at all. I have searched around but another problem I have is even defining what I am searching for since I am not sure what I am looking at to begin with. Just trying "theStartDate as Date" doesn't work.

Comment: See "Associated Values" here (https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html) and here: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-if-case-let/

Comment: It's an enum with Associated value (which are both `Date`). The rest is just extra work when decoding/encoding the associate value.

Answer (score 0):

I see I was getting confused by the extra code now and did not realize this is the same problem I have already solved. This code is working now:

```
    func getDateFromKey(thePage: Page, theKey: String) -> Date? {
        if let theProperty = thePage.properties[theKey] {
            if case .date(let theDateValue) = theProperty.type {
                if case .dateOnly(let theDate) = theDateValue!.start {
                    return theDate
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```